# Text Cleaning and Combining

Tags: r, text-processing

I am trying to combine a variable date with a piece of text so that it looks as follows:

```
time <- c(end_date_override="20180531")
```

This is my code:

```
bb <- Sys.Date()-1
b1 <- paste("c(end_date_override","",sep = "=")
b1<-noquote(b1)
b2 <- as.character(bb)
b3 <- paste(b1,b2)
```

This does not give a result in the format `c(end_date_override="20180531")`

I would appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected return? A named character as time is as you defined it. Or if you want a text returned that includes the data in bb?

Comment: A named character as time is as I have defined it please?

Comment: I want it to take the date applied to bb and create a named char such as this:-

c(end_date_override="20180627")

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
bb <- format(Sys.Date()-1,'%Y%m%d')
b1 <- paste("c(end_date_override=",bb,")", sep='"')
b1 <- noquote(b1)
b1  
[1] c(end_date_override="20180628")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome! Is it the solution you were in search of? If not, it could be possible try something else.

Answer (score 0):

To get a named character as time you can use the following code. The first line is what you need. The others are showing the outcome.

```
b3 <- setNames(as.character(Sys.Date()-1), "end_date_override")

b3
end_date_override 
     "2018-06-28" 

str(b3)
 Named chr "2018-06-28"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "end_date_override"
```